# Extracting the letter of specific index from each word in the list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of words, and I need to extract the letter of specific index from each word in the list to the dictionary, counting their amount. For example, my list consists of "carrot", "sky", "house", "picture" words. Then the dictionary of first indexes would be: {"c":1, "s":1, "h":1, "p":1}, the second indexes: {"a":1, "k":1, "o":1, "i":1}, and so on. It should check each algorithm.

I tried using this code, but it executes the dictionary of all letters that are in the list of words.

```
for el in list:
        for x in el:
            dictionary[x] = dictionary.get(x, 0) + 1
return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the standard [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that can help you. Given an iterable (in your case a list of letters), it gives you a counter object.

So you have to pass it list of letters per index.

I added a word so that counts are not always 0.

```py
from collections import Counter

words = [
    "carrot",
    "sky",
    "house",
    "picture",
    "cinder",  # <-- this word I added !
]

longest_word_length = max(len(word) for word in words)

for index in range(longest_word_length):
    letters = [word[index] for word in words if index < len(word)]
    letters_count = Counter(letters)
    print(f"{index=} {letters_count=}")
```

```
index=0 letters_count=Counter({'c': 2, 's': 1, 'h': 1, 'p': 1})
index=1 letters_count=Counter({'i': 2, 'a': 1, 'k': 1, 'o': 1})
index=2 letters_count=Counter({'r': 1, 'y': 1, 'u': 1, 'c': 1, 'n': 1})
index=3 letters_count=Counter({'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'd': 1})
index=4 letters_count=Counter({'e': 2, 'o': 1, 'u': 1})
index=5 letters_count=Counter({'r': 2, 't': 1})
index=6 letters_count=Counter({'e': 1})
```